# Flutter: How to add bullets points in a TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to add bullets points in a TextField widget similar to the Notes app in IOS?

[image: image from iphone x note]

Comment: I did not try something, I don't have any idea how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Unicode code to achieve this. Add the following Unicode ( **\u25EF** ) to your TextField using TextEditingController. You may also need to change the position of the cursor when adding text to your TextEditingController. This depends on your requirement and you will understand when you test this.

```
TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();



_textController.text = " \u25EF ";
```

Yes. of course you need a custom button or something to trigger this event like in the note of IOS.
You can create a custom keyboard with an extra button to add bullets or a floating deck with a button like the Note app. Or simply give a button on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a checkbox (or similar button) manually when user select it and add to left of textfield. You can define variable on a Row and initialize to Container. Something like that:

```
Widget widget = Container();

[...]

Row(
  children: [
    widget,
    Expanded(child: TextField(...))
  ],
);

[...]

//this activate bullet point
void functionCheckBox(){
  setState({
    widget = Checkbox(value: value, onChanged: onChanged);
  });
}
```

I dont know if it's the best solution or if exists a plugin that does something like that.